# I don't know how to solve this limit? Can you do it for me?

Tags: limits

Find the limit when $x$ approaches zero of $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}{\frac{1-\cos(1-\cos x)}{x^4}}$$

My teacher already told us that the result is $1/8$

Comment: Got to applaud the honest approach.

Answer (score 6):

I use that $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac  1 2$$

Now, consider the following manipulation
 $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(1-\cos x )}{x^4}=\\ \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(1-\cos x )}{(1-\cos x )^2}\frac {(1-\cos x )^2}{x^4}=\\ \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(1-\cos x )}{(1-\cos x )^2}\left(\frac {1-\cos x }{x^2}\right)^2=$$

When $x\to 0$, $1-\cos x \to 0$, so

$$\lim\limits_{u\to 0}\frac{1-\cos u}{u^2}\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac {1-\cos x }{x^2}\right)^2=\frac 1 2 \frac 1 4=\frac 1 8$$

Comment: Nice solution..

Answer (score 5):

What about the L'Hospital rule?
$$\frac{1-\cos(1-\cos x)}{x^4} $$
Differentiate both the nominator and the denominator: 
$$\big(1-\cos(1-\cos x)\big)' = \sin(1-\cos x)\cdot(1-\cos x)' = \sin(1-\cos x)\cdot\sin x $$
and so on..

Comment: @Cameron Buie $0\over0$ seems indeterminant to me...

Comment: @CameronBuie, the first person to edit the question got it wrong. Berci's version, a single fraction, is what was originally posted.

Comment: @CameronBuie $1-\cos(1-\cos(0))=1-\cos(1-1)=1-\cos(0)=1-1=0$. The denominator is clearly $0$. Have I made an error?

Comment: @Daryl, Cameron was reacting to an incorrect version of the expression that was visible for about ten minutes, until I fixed it to agree with the actual question asked. You are doing fine.